# An Olympiad problem ( need explanation to the given answer)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

$P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $3n$ such that

\begin{eqnarray*} P(0) = P(3) = \cdots &=& P(3n) = 2, \\ P(1) = P(4) = \cdots &=& P(3n-2) = 1, \\ P(2) = P(5) = \cdots &=& P(3n-1) = 0, \quad\text{ and }\\ && P(3n+1) = 730.\end{eqnarray*}
Determine $n$.

Today I just stumbled upon this problem while I was reading  a book. I spent about an hour on solving it but to no avail. On searching the internet I found that the problem is from USAMO 1984 test. I have tried using all the fundamental polynomial theory,  use of binomial coefficients and some basic algebra. The internet did give me a solution but it used something named Lagrange interpolation formula or something which I don't have any idea of.  Can someone please help me to work out this problem.

$\mathbf{Edit: }$
Some of you have posted very useful links. I liked the link

https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/usa/usoln/usol845.html.

But I could not understand what the answer means to say.  Can someone please explain whatever the link tries to answer in a better way

Comment: http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php? and https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/usa/usoln/usol845.htmltitle=1984_USAMO_Problems/Problem_5

Comment: See if this helps you: https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/usa/usoln/usol845.html

Comment: I did, that's why there are two links in the comment

Comment: See here also: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h62982p841989